# import python model from other folder

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I'm trying to import python module
from pbi-> backend ->to_pbi.py
and my main module is obiee->backend ->backend_migration
how to do it?

[image: check this pickture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-programmatically) for this

Taken straight from the documentation:

Folder structure:

```
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_bar.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module_foo.py

$ cat bar/__init__.py
from . import module_bar

$ cat bar/module_bar.py

def run():
    print("module_bar imported")


$ cat foo/module_foo.py
import importlib.util
import sys

def load_module():
    fn = "custom"    
    fp = "/home/../bar/__init__.py"
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(fn,fp)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[spec.name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module

print(load_module().module_bar.run())

$ python3.8 foo/module_foo.py
module_bar imported
```